# JQuery Datatables fnDraw with addClass

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to have table with read/unread rows. The server-side script provides a hidden column with read/unread status and I use this to add 'unread class to the needed rows. I mark rows as unread at the initialization with

```
"fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, jason) {
for (i=0; i<oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay();i++) {
    if (oSettings.aoData[i]._aData[10]==0) {
        $(oSettings.aoData[i].nTr).addClass('unread');
    }
}
}
```

And this works fine. However I have a buttion that call table_refresh function:

```
function table_refresh() {
var oSettings = $('#dtable').dataTable().fnSettings();
$('#dtable').dataTable().fnDraw(oSettings);
for (i=0; i<oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay();i++) {
    if (oSettings.aoData[i]._aData[10]==0) {
        $(oSettings.aoData[i].nTr).addClass('unread');
    }
}
}
```

and it does not add 'unread' class to the needed rows. I have tried to put fnDraw before the parsing of rows and after it but it has no effect, i.e. all rows has no unread class which it should. If I refresh the page and the table initialize again I see all classes properly added. So somehow I can not add a class only on fnDraw for some reason.

Comment: if you can create the extra column with server side code, why not just add the class directly to the row?

Comment: That could be a good solution but I how can I do that? The server-side script generates a JSON array to be inserted INTO each TR of the datatable. The table does not expects any TR formating itself, only the TD formating